# How to create route in OpenShift?

Tags: .net-core, yaml, swagger, openshift, openshift-origin

I have gone through this [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/3.11/html/developer_guide/dev-guide-routes) and trying to create a route.

Here is the YAML Definition-

```
- apiVersion: v1
    kind: Route
    metadata:
      name: ${APP_NAME}-${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}-${BRANCH}
      namespace: ${NAMESPACE}
    spec:
      host: ${APP_NAME}-${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}.abc.com
      path: /${ENV_ROUTE}
      port:
        targetPort: 8080-tcp
      tls:
        termination: edge
      to:
        kind: Service
        name: ${APP_NAME}-${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}-${BRANCH}
        weight: 100
      wildcardPolicy: None
    status:
      ingress:
        - conditions:
          host: ${APP_NAME}-${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}.abc.com
          routerName: router
          wildcardPolicy: None
```

This works: **myservice-dev-abc.com**

trying to create a route for **myservice-dev-abc.com/myapp/**

After deployment, the application not accessible. Get the below error.

> **SwaggerUIBundle is not defined**

Maybe I am unable to find something mentioned in the document.

Comment: A question and a note: it is a bit weird to use port 8080 with encryption.  That said, are you sure you're not getting a request on the service, and getting that error being returned by the service?

Comment: This definitely looks like your application answering with that swaggerUI stuff. Maybe some relative path issue? And @caxcaxcoatl: this is norrmal, the tls.termination: edge makes your ingress (haproxy) terminate TLS on the proxy, querying the backend using http.

Comment: Thanks, @SYN; I overlooked the `target` in `targetPort` :)